# Chrome Extension with Google Calendar API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am new to OAuth/2 in Chrome Extensions and from what I've read there seem to be two ways to do it: 
[Chrome.identity](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity.html)
[Tutorial OAuth](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth.html)

My ultimate goal is to build a simple Chrome Extension that pulls the current event and directly accesses the respective deeplink. Can somebody point me into the right direction how - if possible using OAuth2/identity - I can pull calendar information within the background.js? I want to avoid popups.